# How do I make the javascript more fluid? it seems to lag when two things are happening at once

Tags: javascript

I have created this website but noticed the javascript image slider seems to lag the menu pointer when a image transition is happening..

Anyone got any tips for optimization or ideas on how I could resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Website: http://roseground.co.uk/index.html

edit: P.S I have used nivoslider :)

Comment: I withdrew my answer.  You mean the top menu, with the little green bar animation, not the slideshow nav menu.  I'd either have to take a greater look at it, or say that JS wasn't really designed to handle multithreaded animations.  This could be a proc limit, or you may be able to add a hook somewhere in the nivo slideshow, which might allow other animations to process.  Something like a setTimeout(0) generally relinquishes control to other processes.

Comment: win... i was actualy going to stop the transition if the user is hovering on the link.. once the user had finished hovering on the links it would allow transition

Comment: In that case, I undeleted my answer :)

Comment: haha XD was very useful ty.. im new to programming and its nice to know when your on the right lines!.. i guess when it works logicaly as a solution.. then it works!

Comment: You got it working, that's what matters.  I tried to overwrite some of the nivo-slider from firebug, but it didn't work (I was getting annoyed that when you hit the forward/back slides, it wasn't stoping the current animation and going to the next).  You should post your answer up here so others can see what you did.

Comment: yeah ill do that tomorrow :) its 4:21 am at the mo haha.. enough programming for one night ;)

Answer (score 0):

This answer doesn't address speeding up the JS on the site, but it will address helping the site load faster, which is part of the concern.

I watched you page load, and it made multiple downloads for multiple images. If you visit spriteme.org, you can use their bookmarklet to make a single sprite for your site. Having to download one image is much quicker than downloading many images. Check it out. It will help your site.

Comment: thanks I will check that out. It would probably be worth turning all the small images into sprites.

Answer (score 0):

See: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

I don't have time to look into your script but you will need to put a `.stop(true,true)` to stop the previous animation

Comment: thanks for the response.. much appriciated.. so you mean i need to stop the nivo image slider animation while a user is hovering over a link? to stop the conflict

Comment: unfortunately, not even nivo-slider's demo does what you want